# moshi nullable list fails with "required value"

Tags: kotlin, moshi

The following works:

```
package com.squareup.moshi.problem

import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Foo(
        val bar: String?
)

fun main() {
    val adapter=Moshi.Builder().build().adapter<Foo>(Foo::class.java)
    adapter.fromJson("{}")
}
```

but when using a list it fails:

```
package com.squareup.moshi.problem

import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Foo(
        val bar: List<String>?
)

fun main() {
    val adapter=Moshi.Builder().build().adapter<Foo>(Foo::class.java)
    adapter.fromJson("{}")
}
```

with:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Required value 'bar' missing at $
        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.missingProperty(Util.java:605)
        at com.squareup.moshi.problem.FooJsonAdapter.fromJson(FooJsonAdapter.kt:44)
        at com.squareup.moshi.problem.FooJsonAdapter.fromJson(FooJsonAdapter.kt:16)
        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:40)
        at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:43)
        at com.squareup.moshi.problem.MoshiProblemKt.main(MoshiProblem.kt:13)
        at com.squareup.moshi.problem.MoshiProblemKt.main(MoshiProblem.kt)
```

How can I make it work for a list?
Here is a repo showing the problem: https://github.com/ligi/moshi_problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was actually this bug in moshi:

https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/990

hat tip @cketti for pointing me to the issue.

Comment: Seeing this issue again in 11/2/2022

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you set a corresponding model.

   ```
   @GET("/info/")
   suspend fun getInfo(@Query("id")): Info
   ```

Maybe it shouldn't be `Info`, but another type. Also there might be changes in backend and structure of the model had changed.

2. Make sure a required field in the model can be `null`. For instance, if `Info` is a data class with two fields: `id` and `name`, a `name` can be `null` in some cases.

   ```
    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Info(
        @Json(name = "id")
        val id: Int,

        @Json(name = "name")
        val name: String? // "?" means nullable
    )
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If the bar json value is null means it should be like this

**json**

```
{
"bar": null
}
```

so it should be

```
adapter.fromJson("{"bar":null}")
```

Comment: thanks - but this a) produces the same error and b) is not what I want - I want to be able to omit the field in the json